# NoSuchElementException when PageFactory is not used

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, page-factory

Since PageFactory is deprecated in latest selenium version of C#, I'm trying to re-write my existing PageObjects like shown in the below code snippet. Everything works like before except when the elements are yet to be loaded. I have written ExplicitWaitConditions before interacting with them, but I'm getting NoSuchElementException at FindElement(By.Id("email")) itself before it reaches ExplicitWaitConditions. It works fine when I use PageFactory.
Help and suggestions are much appreciated

```
        private IWebDriver driver;
        public LoginPage(IWebDriver _driver)
        {
            driver = _driver;
            //if (driver != null)
            //{
            //    PageFactory.InitElements(driver, this);
            //}
        }

        //[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "email")]
        //public IWebElement txtUserName { get; set; }

        //No such element exception is thrown by below line
        public IWebElement txtUserName => driver.FindElement(By.Id("email"));
```

Basically what I'm trying to understand is how do you achieve lazy initialization without using PageFactory. Since the error is thrown before the element is even accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "this" like below

```
  private IWebDriver _driver;
    public LoginPage(IWebDriver _driver)
    {
        this._driver = _driver;
    }

private IWebElement FooElement
    {
        get
        {
            return this._driver.FindElement(By.Id("foo"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edited the question, please let me know if you have any idea about lazy initialization of WebElements.

Comment: Tried this too. Even though the guy "JimEvans" has mentioned in the github issue that the code you posted above is lazy initialized that's not the case. For reference I'm talking about the github issue from here "https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/4387". Anyway I ended up using the SeleniumExtras.PageObjects nuget package for PageFactory  still I would like to know how lazy initilization could be achieved.